# Neural Network gives same Output no matter what

Tags: python, neural-network

Ive been coding a Neural Network that can classify certain poses i am in. Specific Dance Poses. My Input is 33 Points each made of an x and y coordinate, so in total my input layer is made out of 66 neurons. My Output layer currently only exists of 3. At First I had 1 Hidden Layer with 20 Neurons. Ive changed it to 2 Layers each with 40. That was just a test and is not based on any logical thinking because frankly I have no idea of how to know how many layers or neurons you need.
Its just a solution someone gave but it didnt work either. I believe the Problem is my input values are quite large and after put through the activation function (i am using sigmoid) they are all pretty similiar.

Also the Neural Network is based on the digit classification Neural Network from a tutorial on youtube, but i understand every line fully.

Here is the code if you have any further questions just ask them.

```
import os.path
import numpy as np


class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, learn_rate):
        self.dances = ["Neutral", "Disco 1", "Disco 2"]
        self.lr = learn_rate
        self.correct = 0
        self.accuracy = 0

        self.total = 10

        if not os.path.isfile("data/weights_i_h1.npy"):
            self.w_i_h1, self.w_h1_h2, self.w_h2_o, self.b_i_h1, self.b_h1_h2, self.b_h2_o = self.initialize_values()

        else:

            self.w_i_h1 = np.load("data/weights_i_h1.npy")
            self.w_h1_h2 = np.load("data/weights_h1_h2.npy")
            self.w_h2_o = np.load("data/weights_h2_o.npy")
            self.b_i_h1 = np.load("data/biases_i_h1.npy")
            self.b_h1_h2 = np.load("data/biases_h1_h2.npy")
            self.b_h2_o = np.load("data/biases_h2_o.npy")

    def initialize_values(self):
        w_i_h1 = np.random.uniform(-.5, .5, (40, 66))
        w_h2_o = np.random.uniform(-.5, .5, (40, 40))
        w_h1_h2 = np.random.uniform(-.5, .5, (3, 40))
        b_i_h1 = np.zeros((40, 1))
        b_h1_h2 = np.zeros((40, 1))
        b_h2_o = np.zeros((3, 1))

        return w_i_h1, w_h2_o, w_h1_h2, b_i_h1, b_h1_h2, b_h2_o

    def getAccuracy(self):
        accuracy = round((self.correct / (10 * self.epochs)) * 100, 2)
        return accuracy

    """
    labels:
    1: Neutral
    2: Disco 1 (up)
    3: Disco 2 (down)
    """

    def training(self, points, label):
        l = np.array(label)
        l.shape += (1,)
        points = np.array(points)
        points.shape += (1,)

        h1_pre = self.b_i_h1 + self.w_i_h1 @ points
        h1 = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-h1_pre))

        h2_pre = self.b_h1_h2 + self.w_h1_h2 @ h1
        h2 = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-h2_pre))
        # Output layer
        o_pre = self.b_h2_o + self.w_h2_o @ h2
        o = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-o_pre))

        # Cost

        e = 1 / len(o) * np.sum((o - l) ** 2, axis=0)
        self.correct += int(np.argmax(o) == np.argmax(l))

        # Backpropagation
        delta_o = o - l
        self.w_h2_o += -self.lr * delta_o @ np.transpose(h2)
        self.b_h2_o += -self.lr * delta_o

        delta_h2 = np.transpose(self.w_h2_o) @ delta_o * (h2 * (1 - h2))
        self.w_h1_h2 += -self.lr * delta_h2 @ np.transpose(h1)
        self.b_h1_h2 += -self.lr * delta_h2

        delta_h1 = self.w_h1_h2 @ delta_h2 * (h1 * (1 - h1))
        self.w_i_h1 += -self.lr * delta_h1 @ np.transpose(points)
        self.b_i_h1 += -self.lr * delta_h1
        if np.argmax(o) == np.argmax(l):
            print("---------------------")
            print(self.dances[o.argmax()])
            print(self.correct)
            print("---------------------")

    def save(self):
        np.save("data/weights_i_h1.npy", self.w_i_h1)
        np.save("data/weights_h1_h2.npy", self.w_h1_h2)
        np.save("data/weights_h2_o.npy", self.w_h2_o)
        np.save("data/biases_i_h1.npy", self.b_i_h1)
        np.save("data/biases_h1_h2.npy", self.b_h1_h2)
        np.save("data/biases_h2_o.npy", self.b_h2_o)

    def classify_input(self, points):
        points = np.array(points)
        points.shape += (1,)
        points = (points - 450) / 248.3277

        h1_pre = self.b_i_h1 + self.w_i_h1 @ points
        h1 = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-h1_pre))

        h2_pre = self.b_h1_h2 + self.w_h1_h2 @ h1
        h2 = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-h2_pre))
        # Output layer
        o_pre = self.b_h2_o + self.w_h2_o @ h2
        o = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-o_pre))
        print(self.dances[o.argmax()])

        """
        print("--------------------------------")
        print("Input:", points)
        print("H1:", h1)
        print("H2:", h2)
        print("o:", o)
        print("--------------------------------")"""

        return o.argmax()
```

Only tried changing the number of layers and neurons but it didnt really make a change i noticed

Comment: I realised that my return in the initialize_values method are not right or at least dont match to the variables i declare with the method but even with that fixxed it still doesnt work

Comment: Actually found another thing I forgot to remove after testing but in the classify input function I am using a function to make the value of the poits smaller however that didn’t affect it even when I had it correctly used